# flashvar isn't passing query string

Tags: php, flash

I've added a textfield on the stage. In the html file I've added this line:

```
<PARAM NAME=FlashVars VALUE="<?php echo($QUERY_STRING);?>">
```

So when I enter www.mysite.nl?testvariable=2, the flashvar 'testvariable' which has a value of '2' is being passed to flash

In Flash I'm using:

```
var FlashVars:Object = this.loaderInfo.parameters;
for (var variable:String in FlashVars)
{
   myText.text=variable + ":" + FlashVars[variable];
}
```

But it doesn't show my passed variable/value. Instead it shows  in the textfield. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think that should be `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, unless you're defining your own variable.

Comment: That doesn't do much either. When I use www.mysite.nl?testvariable=2 and view the source code I still see <PARAM NAME=FlashVars VALUE="<?php echo($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);?>"> and in the Flash text field I see <?php echo($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);?>"

Comment: Duh!!! My mistake. Instead of index.php I was using index.html so no php was processed haha The $_server['query_string'] part was correct though

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer and mark it as correct when you can, in that case.

Comment: Im hoping you are sanitizing that `$QUERY_STRING` variable.

Comment: @andrewsi For some reason I can't mark that as the answer. There isn't a checkmark to click on.

Comment: @jiggy1965 - I didn't add it as an answer; since you figured out it was an issue with the calling file being .html, you should add your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] was the answer as andrewsi said. And I made the mistake not using .php as an extension.